# Android Studio - Cannot Lock System Folders Problem - MAC OS X

Tags: macos, android-studio

Recently I am not successding to start my Android Studio on my MAC OS, despite I had used it several times without problem.

Recently when I attempt to start the Android Studio it pops a big internal error message "Cannot Lock System Folders".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnYMa.png)

I searched for information, something about this problem on MAC OS, but unfortunately I haven't reached to any conclusion and most of all I cannot use the Android Studio anymore.

Does anyone have came across with this problem and was able to sort it out?
Thanks is advance for any help

Comment: I already tried to refresh the SystemConfiguration by deleting it from /Library/Preferences but that did not worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what was going wrong with Android Studio.

Somehow there's a problem of linkage when user's home folder is moved to other volume different from the one used by the system.

In my case I have moved my Home folder to a secondary drive (ExFat) to be shareable between MAC OS X // Linux // Windows. My main OS is MAC, then ROS and other programming I use Linux and to program some ST microcontroller and design some CAD object I must use Windows.

That was a hit after making all A.S. application's folder 777.

After returning the Home folder back to MAC OS system volume all Java libraries were linked again and the Android Studio started normally.

In my case the problem is partially solved. Need to figure out haw I can make the Android Studio running with my Home folder located in non-system volume.